# ¿Cómo obtener el nombre de paquete de cualquier app abierta actualmente desde un servicio?

Tags: android, app

Hola a todos tengo el siguiente problema. Estoy tratando de obtener el nombre de paquete de la app que se encuentra en primer plano, es decir, la app que está en uso actualmente por el usuario. De esa manera cada vez que se abra una app distinta puedo lanzar una actividad con algunas opciones a escoger para el usuario.
ACLARACIÓN:
No confundir con obtener el nombre de paquete de mi app. Sino más bien de la app que esté en uso en tiempo real

Comment: ¿Como has tratado de realizar esto, agrega el código? Abierta te refieres a si esta visible o que este abierta y en background.

Comment: Con abierta me refiero a que esté visible en primer plano

Answer (score 3):

Puedes obtener el package name de la aplicación mediante el contexto de esta forma:

```
String nombrePaquete = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
```

---

Si deseas obtener el "package name" de otra aplicación la cual esta abierta, no es posible por cuestiones de seguridad.

Comment: Definitivamente no es la respuesta solicitada. Lógicamente este método solo devolverá el nombre de paquete de mi app. Pero lo que trato de saber es cómo obtener el de la app que esté abierta en primer plano en cualquier momento

Comment: @EJV por eso es importante realizar la pregunta en base a [ask], para que no existan mal entendidos y obtengas la ayuda de una forma rápida, revisa mi actualización,.

Comment: Gracias Elenasys por tu sugerencia. Voy a intentar ser más específico las próximas veces y así evitar malentendidos. Gracias

Comment: Se qué si es posible hacerlo porque varias app en el mercado lo hacen y en todas las versiones de Android. Por ejemplo, Samsung Max. Detecta la app en primer plano y lanza una actividad transparente para solicitar si desea permitir o no. Esto es solo un ejemplo, hay muchísimas app más que también lo hacen. Quisiera saber cómo